# Fast loading of data from a linked server ORACLE in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have procedures in DB MSSQL to load data from a linked server ORACLE

in the DB MSSQL there is a tables:

1. table_1 contains a list of orders ID
2. table_2 contains detailed information on orders

In DB MSSQL useds procedure to update and load data into a table_2, procedure uses an operator IN together with CURSOR , it works for a long time.
table_2 contains 1-2 million rows.

Is there any other way / approach for quickly loading data from the ORACLE DBMS into MSSQL using the initial data from the table_1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you want to synchronize data between SQL*Server and Oracle. The best way is to use a commercial product that does this. I have developed some routines in our shop that does this, but it isn't trivial.

The easiest way to do this is if you have an ascending UID. Record the greatest value into a table at the end of the synchronization. The next time you run the synchronization, start with > unique value.

I try to avoid cursors, I use insert/selects. They are much easier to code, run very fast, and fail as a unit. I am copy 600K records every 4 hours from Oracle to SQL Server.

The example below is T*SQL and is executed from SQL*Server. The same code is easily translated into PL/SQL if you need to execute from Oracle. I have done it both ways.

- @last_loaded - track the hightest ID that has been loaded into the databases
- tracker_table - table used to store last_loaded values.
- load_type = 2 - tracker table can be used to track ids for different loads.
- oracledb.. - name of SQL Server linked server to Oracle
- COPYSCHEMA - name of schema containing Oracle table. ALWAYS SPECIFY!
- COPYTABLE  - name of Oracle table from which we are copying

  -- Sample Code

  ```
   DECLARE @last_loaded INT;

   SELECT last_loaded
   INTO @last_loaded
     FROM tracker_table
    WHERE load_type = '2';

   INSERT INTO            LOAD_TABLE ( ID
                                     , COLUMNA
                                     , COLUMNB
                                     , COLUMNC )
   SELECT ID
        , columna
        , columnb
        , columnc
     FROM oracledb..COPYSCHEMA.COPYTABLE
    WHERE ID > coalesce(@last_loaded, 0);

   SELECT MAX(LAST_LOADED)
   INTO @last_loaded
     FROM LOAD_TABLE;

   UPDATE TRACKER_TABLE
     SET
         LAST_LOADED = @last_loaded
    WHERE LOAD_TYPE = 2;
  ```